# $elemMatch dosen't work after $unwind in MongoDB Aggregation Framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongo-java

I have a collection of the following data:

```js
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("51f1fcc08188d3117c6da351"),
  "cust_id" : "abc123",
  "ord_date" : ISODate("2012-10-03T18:30:00Z"),
  "status" : "A",
  "price" : 25,
  "items" : [{
      "sku" : "ggg",
      "qty" : 7,
      "price" : 2.5
    }, {
      "sku" : "ppp",
      "qty" : 5,
      "price" : 2.5
    }]
}
```

I am using the query:

```js
cmd { "aggregate" : "orders" , "pipeline" : [ 
    { "$unwind" : "$items"} , 
    { "$match" : { "items" : { "$elemMatch" : { "qty" : { "$in" : [ 7]}}}}} , 
    { "$group" : { "price" : { "$first" : "$price"} , "items" : { "$push" : { "sku" : "$items.sku"}} , "_id" : { "items" : "$items"}}} , 
    { "$sort" : { "price" : -1}} , 
    { "$project" : { "_id" : 0 , "price" : 1 , "items" : 1}}
]}
```

Not able to understand what is going wrong

Comment: Would be good if you could format your questions, getting a bit annoying to do it for you

Comment: @Sammaye will take care of it next time.

Comment: have you tried it with ONLY the match? perhaps your problem is with another parameter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because you're doing `$match` after `$unwind`. `$unwind` generates a new stream of documents where `items` is no longer an array ([see docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)).

It emits each document as many times as there are items in it.

If you want to select documents with desired element in it and then process all of its documents, you should call `$match` first:

```
db.orders.aggregate(
  { "$match" : { "items" : { "$elemMatch" : { "qty" : { "$in" : [ 7]}}}}},
  { "$unwind" : "$items"},
  ...
);
```

If you want to select items to be processed after `$unwind`, you shoul remove `$elemMatch`:

```
db.orders.aggregate(
  { "$unwind" : "$items"},
  { "$match" : { "items.qty" : { "$in" : [7]}}},
  ...
);
```

In first case you'll get two documents:

```
{ 
  "price" : 25,
  "items" : [
    {"sku" : "ppp"}
  ]
},
{
  "price" : 25,
  "items" : [
    {"sku" : "ggg"}
  ]
}
```

and in second case you'll get one:

```
{
  "price" : 25,
  "items" : [
    {"sku" : "ggg"}
  ]
}
```

**Update**. After `$unwind` your documents will look like:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("51f1fcc08188d3117c6da351"),
  "cust_id" : "abc123",
  "ord_date" : ISODate("2012-10-03T18:30:00Z"),
  "status" : "A",
  "price" : 25,
  "items" : {
    "sku" : "ggg",
    "qty" : 7,
    "price" : 2.5
  }
}
```

Comment: Items is no longer an array yet dot notation works after unwinding? If dot notation works then how do you explain that elemMatch doesn't, your answer is a bit vague on that

Comment: After `$unwind` items will became a single document. Dot notation works for nested objects as well as for arrays.

Comment: But qty is in the root document after unwinding, it isn't nested

Comment: No, it's not. Try `db.orders.aggregate({ "$unwind" : "$items"})` and see what it looks like.

Comment: Ok fair enough, that adds up

Comment: nearly two hours and thank god this answer showed up!

Answer (score 3):

For small number of documents, unwind and match is fine. But large number of documents, it better to do - match ($elemMatch), unwind, and match again.

```
db.orders.aggregate(
  { "$match" : { "items" : { "$elemMatch" : { "qty" : { "$in" : [ 7]}}}}},
  { "$unwind" : "$items"},
  { "$match" : { "items.qty" : { "$in" : [7]}}}
  ...
  ...
);
```

The first match will filter only documents that match qty criteria. Among the selected documents, the second match will remove the subdocuments not matching the qty criteria.